# Can I add the web-link into the XML-documentation?

Tags: .net, xml, sandcastle, xml-documentation

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax.aspx) I see the set of the allowed XML-tags for generation of the documentation (through SandCastle).

Wether exists the additional XML-tag for the link (to web-page) which would be opened through the browser when user press it? If I use `<a href="...:/>` then CHM-file attempts to open the link in its window and I get the script error message.

Comment: Regarding the first question, it is not quite clear what kind of content you want to link to. If you want a link to another type documentation, perhaps using `<see cref="…" />` would suffice?

Comment: @stakx I meant the link to web-page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the MSDN forum post ["Embedding External URLs or Hyperlinks within XML Comments"](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/82d85250-e5ac-48f2-a787-2ca441904c2c/embedding-external-urls-or-hyperlinks-within-xml-comments?forum=csharpide):

> *"To insert an external hyperlink, do just as you do in an html file. For example in your scenario, you can add the credit like this:"*
>
> ```
> /// <summary>
> /// This is a test class.See <a href="http://…">Credits</a>.
> /// </summary>
> ```
>
> *"And a help documentation tool such as SandCastle will process it properly."*
>
> — user Chunsheng Tang

So using `<a>` generally seems like the right way to go.

Unfortunately, you did not say exactly what kind of script error message you're getting.

- The opened web page might simply contain errors itself. If that is the case, there is not much you can do except linking to a different web page.
- The help viewer might open the web page inside its own browser, where script execution is restricted. In this case, you could try adding a `target="_blank"` attribute to the `<a>` element, so that the web page will be opened in a new window or tab.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
/// <summary>
/// A good example <see href="https://example.com"/>.
/// </summary>
```